# batch file to get partial lastmodified string to variable

Tags: batch, wmic

`WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name="W:\\foldername" get lastmodified`

returns something like this

> LastModified
>   **20140612**095434.758265-240

I would like to put this in a batch file to assign the bolded portion of that string to a variable so I can use it later in the batch file.

Any help is appreciated!

This is my batch file so far for reference

```
@echo off
@cls
net use W: \\file\home\ex-employees
cd W:
W:

REM Get user ID
set /p id="Enter ID of user to Archive: "

REM Get last modified code goes here assigned to "LM" variable
REM
REM WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name='W:\\rsink' get lastmodified

REM Join Variables
call set filename=%%%id%%LM%%%

call zipjs.bat zipItem -source %id% -destination .\%filename%.zip -keep yes -force no

rmdir /S /Q %id%

Echo All Done!
@pause
```

Comment: Suggestion rather than answer: You should consider using PowerShell instead, much better for this. No WMI needed.  eg: `$folderDate = Get-Date (Get-Item W:\foldername | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}) -format "yyyyMMdd"`

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not so easy to slot that into his batch file though. It's only a couple of lines to do it in batch.

Comment: @DavidPostill I meant use PS instead of Batch entirely. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 lol. "complexity/obscurity of parsing text output from WMI with a for loop" is trivial when you know what you are doing and I enjoy the challenge :)

Comment: I decided to remove that section of my comment to prevent responses like that, apparently I wasn't quick enough.  Anyhow, in PS, it's even MORE trivial if you know what you're doing.  ;)  But I'm not here to debate this, I simply made a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I would like to put this in a batch file to assign the bolded portion of that string to a variable

```
WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name="W:\\foldername" get lastmodified
```

returns something like this

> LastModified
>
> **20140612**095434.758265-240

You can use a `for /f` loop to do this. Here is a small example.

**GetLastModifiedDate.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
rem GetLastModifedDate.cmd
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem skip header line
rem use findstr to remove blank lines
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%d in ('WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name^="f:\\test" get lastmodified ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  set LM=%%d
  rem required part is alway 8 chars yyyymmdd so strip first 8 chars
  set LM=!LM:~0,8!
  )
echo %LM%
endlocal
```

**Your batch file with the needed modifications:**

```
@echo off
@cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
net use W: \\file\home\ex-employees
cd W:
W:

REM Get user ID
set /p id="Enter ID of user to Archive: "

REM Get last modified code goes here assigned to "LM" variable
rem skip header line
rem use findstr to remive blank lines
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%d in ('WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name^="W:\\rsink" get lastmodified ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  set LM=%%d
  rem required part is alway 8 chars yyyymmdd so strip first 8 chars
  set LM=!LM:~0,8!
  )

REM Join Variables
call set filename=%%%id%%LM%%%

call zipjs.bat zipItem -source %id% -destination .\%filename%.zip -keep yes -force no

rmdir /S /Q %id%

Echo All Done!
@pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Looks good but it throws "No Instance(s) Available." error. Not sure why.

Comment: @LeperMessiah Oops. I forgot to change `f:\\test` to `W:\\rsink` in your batch file. Answer corrected. Please try it again. "No Instance(s) Available." error was because you probably don't have a directory called ``f:\test`